# How to integrate service worker in Angular library?

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-library

I am trying to develop a npm package which I can use in various projects to know whenever there is a build update user will be notified to refresh page.

This concept can be achieved via service-worker in angular, But when I try to add parameter "serviceWorker": true  inside the angular.json of my workspace's library object it is not allowing me and throws error as per below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service worker can only be integrated inside an angular `application`.
You are getting an error because your project is of type `library`.